# Can't set value of an object in an API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need my code to get the current rates using [open-exchange-rates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-exchange-rates), use [money.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/) to convert the currency and set the returned value to a JSON object. But the problem is that the JSON object stays the same it does not get modified:

```
 arr.prices.map(function(object) {
    // get current rate
    oxr.latest(function() {
       fx.base = "USD";
       fx.rates = oxr.rates;
       // convert usd to zmw
       let zmw = fx.convert(object["total"], { from: "USD", to: "ZMW" });
       // set new value
       object["total"] = zmw;
    });         
 });
```

**Update after trying a promise:**
Still not working.

```
  arr.prices.map(function(object) {
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      oxr.latest(function() {
        fx.base = "USD";
        fx.rates = oxr.rates;
        let zmw = fx.convert(object["total"], { from: "USD", to: "ZMW" });

        if (zmw === undefined) {
          reject('Fail')
        } else {
          resolve(zmw);
        }
      });

    })

    p.then((zmw)=>{
      object["total"] = zmw;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Fail')
    })

  });
```

Comment: Promisify `.latest`, then use `Promise.all` to wait for all calls to resolve

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have updated my code with the use of a promise I still get the same result.

Comment: You need to use `Promise.all` to wait for all calls to resolve